# push elements dynamically to array jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, local-storage

I am trying push elements to an array dynamically. But my code is not working. I want to add array elements onclick in jquery. When i push an element its getting added but when i am trying to add second element first element is removed and only second element is added. Not able to add elements dynamically.

This is my code to push elements dynamically:

```
$('#addItemFromAjax').click(function(){
var storage = '{"items":[]}';
var itemObject = JSON.parse(storage);
itemObject["items"].push({"name":data[0].name,"id":data[0].id});
localStorage.setItem('itemList', JSON.stringify(itemObject));
alert(localStorage.getItem('itemList'));
});
```

Comment: Declare array outside of click function and try it.I guess every time you click, the array is initialized

Comment: @Balu Didn't work that way for me

Comment: I mean declare the array at global level in the js file where the click function is handled.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try below code. It will use the localStorage list first if available else will initialize it.

Also you are pushing first element from `data` always, so may need to change as per your requirement!

```
$('#addItemFromAjax').click(function(){
 var storage = localStorage.getItem('itemList') || '{"items":[]}';
 var itemObject = JSON.parse(storage);
 itemObject["items"].push({"name":data[0].name,"id":data[0].id});
 localStorage.setItem('itemList', JSON.stringify(itemObject));
 alert(localStorage.getItem('itemList'));
});
```